# Music playback stops randomly

Tags: music, logging, system, troubleshooting

I have bought the Xperia ZQ (Xperia ZL's alias in Brazil) C6503. I am experiencing a very annoying problem: from time to time the audio playback in any audio app just stops. If I hit play again it will resume normally but I still need to tap the play button which can be a pain specially while driving. I can't remember when this started but I think it is from the first time I tried to play any audio on it.

I think it is an issue with 'Audio Focus' since the playback pauses and will resume gently from where it stopped if I hit the play (or unpause) button.

I used `adb logcat` to register the events logged by the OS while listening to music. When it happened I checked the log and found these lines (which I think represent the moment it stopped playing):

```
D/PowerManagerService( 581): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NetworkStats
D/ConnectivityService( 581): Actual State: DefaultConnectivityState, Current State:DefaultConnectivityState.processMessage what=113
D/ConnectivityService( 581): Actual State: DefaultConnectivityState, Current State: DefaultConnectivityState.processMessage what=113
D/PowerManagerService( 581): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NetworkStats
D/PowerManagerService( 581): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
I/AudioService( 581): Remote Control registerMediaButtonIntent() for PendingIntent{441a9fa0: PendingIntentRecord{441adea8 deezer.android.app broadcastIntent}}
I/AudioService( 581): Remote Control registerMediaButtonIntent() for PendingIntent{42519fe8: PendingIntentRecord{441adea8 deezer.android.app broadcastIntent}}
I/AudioService( 581): AudioFocus requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@426dc7a0gu@42659da8
D/@ AudioController(17666): AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS
D/@ AudioController(17666): Pause requested.
D/PowerManagerService( 581): releaseWakeLock flags=0x20000001 tag=android.media.MediaPlayer
I/AudioService( 581): AudioFocus abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@42944af0com.n7p.atj@425206b0
I/AudioService( 581): AudioFocus abandonAudioFocus(): removing entry for android.media.AudioManager@42944af0com.n7p.atj@425206b0
D/PebbleWatch(17666): Sent com.getpebble.action.NOW_PLAYING for Ambitions from Dead End Kings
```

I was using n7 player (which I guess is `com.n7p.atj@425206b0` in the log) when the playback was interrupted. I think that `I/AudioService( 581): AudioFocus requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@426dc7a0gu@42659da8` did interrupt the n7 player.

I'll try to get more events like this using other apps. Anyone have any clue on how to solve this? I thought I would find some lousy app requesting audio focus randomly but what I got here is AudioManager messing my playback... (assuming I did interpret this correctly).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Some information about my system:

```
Android: 4.1.2
Phone model: C6503
baseband model: 9x15A-ACEFWMAZQ-30110017-11
Kernel: 3.4.0-g298631f-02021-gc1b7814
Version: 10.1.A.1.434
```

Comment: This is probably not going to be super helpful, but when I had this issue I realized that it was because I was accidentally pressing the button on my earphone cable that stops playback.  I have no idea if there were any similar messages logged.  Anyway that might help someone if they're experiencing a similar issue as a result of PEBKAC.